# Sum of Squares - np.inner vs squaring first, then summing

Tags: python, numpy

I was surprised that calling `np.inner` to compute a sum of squares was about 5x faster than calling `np.sum` on a pre-computed array of squares:

[image: sum of squares code]

Any insights into this behavior?  I'm actually interested in a very fast implementation of a sum of squares, so those thoughts are welcome, too.

Answer (score 6):

To check in which modules `np.inner` and `np.sum` are implemented I type

```
>>> np.inner.__module__
'numpy.core.multiarray'
>>> np.sum.__module__
'numpy.core.fromnumeric'
>>> np.__file__
'/Users/uweschmitt/venv_so/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py'
```

If you inspect the actual files, you can see that `numpy.core.multiarray` is a pure C module whereas `numpy.core.fromnumeric` first does some checks and conversions in Python before a second Python function and then a pure C implementation for the actual summation is called.

I suspect that this overhead from the Python interpreter explains the observed timing differences.

To prove my assumption I run the timing with a larger array and get

```
In [8]: a = np.random.random(1000000)
In [9]: %timeit np.inner(a, a)
1000 loops, best of 3: 673 µs per loop
In [10]: %timeit np.sum(a)
1000 loops, best of 3: 584 µs per loop
```

Now run times are quite similar and change a little if you repeat the statements, sometimes `np.sum` wins, somtimes `np.inner`.

For the big array the actual work of `np.sum` is done in C and the constant time overhead from the Python interpreter is negligible.

Comment: It is a good observation, but increasing the number of elements in the array exacerbated the problem for me.  For 1M elements as you have, `np.inner` took 62.2 microseconds, while `np.sum` took 1.04 ms, or almost 17x longer,

Comment: What version of `numpy` do you use ? I have `1.11.0`.

Comment: And: did you run the timing multiple times ?

Comment: v 1.9.2.  Think it's just a version difference?  Where would one look up old numpy version's source code? Yea, I ran it multiple times and the problem behavior persisted.

Comment: First I'll try to run my timing with your numpy version, then I'd check the source code at https://github.com/numpy/numpy/tree/maintenance/1.9.x

Comment: I can not reproduce your observations with `numpy 1.9.2`. On my Machine (Mac) `np.sum` is a bit slower by a factor of about 1.5.

Comment: can you post the output of `np.show_config()` ? Maybe your `numpy` is linked against some optimized blas library !?